# Count for distinct values in union of table one and table two using a subquery

Tags: mysql, database

**Objective:**
I would like to find out the number of unique users who have posted or liked the posts in a particular category.

I have two tables `posts` and `likes` with the following fields

**posts:**

```
id,
user_id,
category
```

**likes:**

```
id,
user_id,
post_id
```

Now, I'd like to find distinct user_id values in `posts` based on a particular category
And distinct user_id values in `likes` but also the union of both these result sets.

I am using the following Mysql query to achieve this:

`SELECT user_id FROM posts WHERE category = 0 union SELECT user_id from likes where likes.post_id in (select id from posts where category = 0)`

I'd like to find out if I am getting the desired result AND if there's a better way to achieve this without having to use the sub-query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only speed up the performance by replacing the subquery by `INNER JOIN`.

```
SELECT
  user_id
FROM posts
WHERE category = 0

UNION

SELECT
  likes.user_id
FROM likes 
INNER JOIN posts 
ON likes.post_id = posts.id 
WHERE posts.category = 0;
```

It will be much faster if `likes.post_id` is indexed properly and `posts.id` is `PK/indexed`.

Comment: Hey there, 71!
I already tried what you've suggested here.
I am getting the following error in this case:
`Column 'user_id' in field list is ambiguous`

Comment: Please try now. Corrected! Glad that you decoded my name :p

Comment: I am getting a different result set than I was getting in the query I've used.
Could you also explain why that is?

Comment: May be I guessed the problem wrong. Actually I thought the same `user_ids` are across the two tables under same `post_id` and `category`.

Comment: `posts.user_id` and `likes.user_id` can differ. right? If yes, then I am wrong.

Comment: Added objective above.

Comment: got it! updated. You cannot avoid `UNION` in this case. But can speed up performance by using `INNER JOIN` if indexed properly.

Comment: I guess that'll do! :)

Comment: Again getting column is ambiguous error.
Sorted it by finding posts.user_id in the second query.
But wonder why we are not using likes.user_id instead? What's the difference?

Comment: Sorry again mate! I just let the same error twice to happen. it should have been `likes.user_id`. updated.